# How to avoid using the principal branch?

Tags: complex, variable-definitions

How can I make Mathematica to use $Log[-1]=i\pi+2i\pi*n$ with $n\in\mathbb{Z}$?

Currently, mathematica set $Log(-1)=i\pi$ and when I try to redefine the value of $Log[-1]$ I get the message "Set::write: Tag Log in $Log[-1]$ is Protected".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I make Mathematica to use Log[−1]=iπ+2iπ∗n with n∈Z?

I would not advice doing this but you can do

```
Log[-1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ClearAll[n]
Unprotect[Log]
Log[-1] := I*Pi + 2*I*Pi*n;
Protect[Log]
Log[-1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Update**

As mentioned in comment below thanks to @bmf, an alternative is to define your own `log` function.  Taken from comment:

> log[-1] := I Pi + 2 I Pi n and then replace /. Log[-1] -> log[-1]

This will be safer approach than modifying the build-in function.

**Update**

> Is it possible to make it generate a different n when a Log[-1] is
> generated?

I am going in the dark here. But may be this is what you meant as I have to go.

```
ClearAll[n];
n = -1;
log[-1] := (n++; I Pi + 2 I Pi n );
```

And now each time you use it, it will update `n` by 1. Feel free to modify as you need.

```
expr = Log[-1] + x;
expr /. Log[-1] -> log[-1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can do the same for the Build-in function `Log[-1]` if you do not want to the use `log[-1]` solution.

Comment: As you said in your answer, this is in general not advised. Perhaps, you could also explain that one can use `log[-1] := I Pi + 2 I Pi n` and then replace `/. Log[-1] -> log[-1]` for clarity and completeness.

Comment: @bmf, Your solution is also good one but I assumed OP wanted to redefine the buildin `Log` itself.  But will add your solution as alternative.

Comment: that is my understanding as well regarding what the OP wanted and I upvoted your answer because it answers directly. I just mentioned it as a small extra since you also made a related comment :-)

Comment: The actual application of this is not so good. Since, it gives the same value of n every time a Log[-1] is generated. Is it possible to make it generate a different n when a Log[-1] is generated?

Comment: @Yair I am not sure I understand what you mean by **Is it possible to make it generate a different n when a Log[-1] is generated?** how will the function know what `n` to use? why not change `n` to anyvalue you want after the log[-1] is called? Or put it as argument to the function? Can you you give examples of what you want? or do you mean each time it is called, you wanted it to automatically increment some global `n` value? it is not clear what you want.

Comment: @Nasser I think the following is sought after `ClearAll[n]
Unprotect[Log]
Log[-1, n_] := I*Pi + 2*I*Pi*n;
Protect[Log]
Log[-1, n]` such that `Log[-1, 3]` evaluates to `7 i π`

Comment: @bmf Yes, that is a good way. I suggested this in my comment. Well, now the OP can choose whichever approach they want. The specification is not clear to me. But they can try both methods and pick the one they want.

Comment: @Nasser yup, I agree. OP should have more than enough by now to continue

Comment: @Nasser Good question. I compute an integral on a Reimann surface. Once the integration is over, one have to plug the upper and lower limits of the integration and each of these involve a negative log. What I want is that when computing the upper limit, $Log[-1]=i\pi+2\pi*n$ while for the lower limit, $Log[-1]=i\pi+2\pi*m$.